# Rails - rack::offline not permanently caching vendor javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm building a Rails app that needs to be able to load a particular view/action while a user is offline, using the rack::offline gem... some of the functionality of the page in question is dependent on jQuery, and I added jQuery 2.2.4 to the vendor javascript folder.  jQuery 2.2.4 is required in the application.js file, but the problem that I am having is that jQuery doesn't seem to be getting added to the cache, and the jQuery functionality is lost if the user refreshes the browser while offline.

I was able to temporarily resolve this issue by literally pasting the entire jQuery script into the view in question, but that is definitely not a practical solution.

How can I make sure the jQuery file in my vendor scripts is cached along with the HTML for he view in question?

The html element for the view includes the manifest attribute...

```
<html manifest="/application.manifest">
```

and from routes.rb

```
get '/application.manifest' => Rails::Offline
```

from my application.js file

```
//= require jquery-2.2.4.js
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And, to be comprehensive, here's the manifest...

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 70f990270c71e8065f366ef4b2d73c870e89f37e4dbef32b57e0135c84b90001
404.html
422.html
500.html

NETWORK:
*
```

The first time I visit the page while offline (after caching), no problem, it pulls up the working cached version.  However, as I mentioned, if I refresh the page, it loses the jQuery functionality ($ is undefined, etc.), although the HTML remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleased to say that I was able to figure this out...

You'll notice in my original post, there was no jQuery being included in the manifest - this is a problem! First thing, I needed to make sure that jQuery was tucked into my `public` folder - I added it to `public/javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.js`.

Now my manifest looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 70f990270c71e8065f366ef4b2d73c870e89f37e4dbef32b57e0135c84b90001
404.html
422.html
500.html
javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.js

NETWORK:
*
```

Lovely!

Now, despite the fact that I had put jQuery into the public folder, it wasn't automatically loading when I navigated to the view that was being cached (I'd love it if someone could help me figure out why that is happening, but it's not the end of the world).  So, I added `<script> src="/javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>`  to the head of the layout file associated with the view, and boom, there ya go.

Now jQuery is being cached appropriately, my app runs offline.

Comment: I was initially operating under the assumption that the view with the `manifest` attribute would be automatically cached along with its dependencies.  I was wrong!